# When I make a change in style.css the changes are not shown in Genesis Framework

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

Basically I just want to change the border of the product images in wordpress using woocommerce and　Genesis framework (Jessica child theme), but when I do the changes in Style.css (using Sublime test) and I restart XAMPP, I can not see any change, everything it's exactly the same.

In the original style.css we can find this:

```
body.woocommerce-page div.product div.images img,
body.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images img {
    border: 5px solid #e7e9ea;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

And I replaced the code for:

```
body.woocommerce-page div.product div.images img,
body.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images img {
    border: 2px solid #e7e9ea;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

But I can't see any changes.

Some ideas?

Comment: Can you open the file on the browser and see if the changes are there?

Comment: @Ibu If I open the style.css from the browser, http://localhost/wp-content/themes/jessica/style.css, I can see the changes there perfectly! But even if I refresh the page, it's still displaying the old style.

Comment: Check on the chrome inspector if you are looking at the same file

Answer (score 1):

To me the same thing happened and the changes in css are only shown after stopping the execution of the web page and restarting it or even closing the netbeans and reopening it. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know it's not only me with this problem, I tried to stop all servers, reset everything but...same results.

Comment: There are times that you have to turn off the computer even. But I would try to put border color with border-color in another line.